# SQL Oracle to Microsoft SQL Server trunc(current_date, 'DD') converting to trunc(current_date, 'DD')

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm converting from SQL Oracle to Microsoft SQL Server

**`>= trunc(current_date, 'DD')`** converting to  **`>= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())`**

But it's not giving me the same result.

My question is what does `trunc(current_date, 'DD')` look like (What format?)? I'm not able to test it as the old database has been deleted.

Should the conversion be **`convert(varchar, getdate(), 105)`** instead?

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to store this as `string` type in mssql, this is the nearest datetime format that I can think of.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101'), 126) + 'Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

`Trunc` in oracle will always return `date` as an output.

`Trunc` by `DD` will truncate time portion and give the floor date, not the nearest date.

So consider that your_date is 24-sep-2019 05:30:00 PM.

```
Select trunc(your_date, 'DD') from dual
```

Will give following result

```
24-sep-2019 
-- see time portion is truncated 
-- and return type is also date
```

Now, you can convert this query accordingly in mssql.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server for following query you get the out put as '`25 Sep 2019`'

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 106)
```

In Oracle to get the same date output as '`25 Sep 2019`' you can use the below query.

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR(
    TRUNC(TO_DATE( '25 Sep 2019 15:35:32', 'DD Mon yyyy HH24:MI:SS' )),'DD Mon yyyy')
FROM
  dual;
```